# Get last element of pipeline in powershell

Tags: powershell, pipeline

This might be weird, but stay with me.
I want to get only the last element of a piped result to be assigned to a varaiable.
I know how I would do this in "regular" code of course, but since this must be a one-liner.

More specifically, I'm interested in getting the file extension when getting the result from an FTP request `ListDirectoryDetails`.

Since this is done within a string expansion, I can't figure out the proper code.

Currently I'm getting the last 3 hars, but that is real nasty.

```
New-Object PSObject -Property @{

    LastWriteTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($tempDate, "MMM dd HH:mm",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)

    Type = $(if([int]$tempSize -eq 0) { "Directory" } else { $tempName.SubString($tempName.length-3,3) })

    Name = $tempName

    Size = [int]$tempSize

}
```

My idea was doing something similar to

```
    $tempName.Split(".") | ? {$_ -eq $input[$input.Length-1]}
```

that is, iterate over all, but only take out where the element I'm looking at is the last one of the input-array.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 27):

A few ways to do this:

```
$name = 'c:\temp\aaa.bbb.ccc'

# way 1
$name.Split('.') | Select-Object -Last 1

# way 2
[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($name)

# or if the dot is not needed
[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($name).TrimStart('.')
```

Answer (score 11):

In general, getting the last element in the pipeline would be done using `Select -Last 1` as Roman suggests above.  However, an alternate and easier way to do this if the input is a simple array is to use array slicing e.g.:

```
PS> $name = "c:\temp\aaa.bbb.txt"
PS> $name.Split('.')[-1]
txt
```

Was your intent to get the file's extension or basename?  Because it seems that the `Type` property already contains the extension for the filename.