# Grab the latest volume using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

I'm struggling trying to grab the latest **volume/Drive** using PowerShell

I have a result of a PowerShell look like this

```
PS C:\Users\me> Get-WMIObject Win32_Volume | select Name

Name
----
C:\
D:\
E:\
\\?\Volume{021a6bbd-0b97-4973-824a-7c635e362f09}\
\\?\Volume{bae1c1d6-59c3-44b1-9360-b7d3101c0e92}\


PS C:\Users\me>
```

If I want to access just this

`E:`

How can I filter out to `:\` with the highest alphabetical order ?

I've been trying so many options using `Select-String`, but seems to get worse result.

Comment: What about something like `Get-psdrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Sort-Object -Property Root | Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty Root` ?

Comment: that is amazingly works. please answer it. it's your.

Comment: Latest or last ?

Comment: latest one according the post I asked.

Answer (score 2):

The ones you want don't start with "\\". The drive letters may be returned in any order, so you need to sort them and take the last one:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Volume | Where-Object {$_.Name -NotLike '\\*'} | select Name | Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object -Last 1
```

Or, if the drive letter is known to be in the range A to Z, then it would be more sensible to use `-Like '[A-Z]*'` instead of `-NotLike '\\*'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Volume | where {$_.Name -eq "E:\"}
```

this should give you a list of objects wich you can access like an array. Also there is a lot of useful information here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/2007.04.powershell.aspx

Comment: I only grab the latest one only. I already know how to grab the list.

Comment: there is also a sort and a last 
Sort: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-6
Last: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546567/get-last-element-of-pipeline-in-powershell